# pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: pyspark, pycharm, hdfs

pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /F:/spark/sample_files/column_containing_JSON_data.csv from F:/spark/sample_files/column_containing_JSON_data.csv is not a valid DFS filename.

**I am giving local input file path(as given below) but it is trying to access hdfs path(/F:/spark/sample_files/column_containing_JSON_data.csv). Throwing above error.**

inputFile=spark.read.option("header",True).option("multiline",True).option("escape",""")
.csv('F:\spark\sample_files\column_containing_JSON_data.csv')

Comment: File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", in csv
return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
File "C:\Users\Abhay Bisht\PycharmProjects\GKCStoresPipeline\venv\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
return_value = get_return_value(
File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 117, in deco
raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /F:/Project/Data/Inputs/Sales_Landing/SalesDump_29062021 from F:/Project/Data/Inputs/Sales_Landing/SalesDump_29062021 is not a valid DFS filename.

Comment: I have even re installed pyspark  and again facing the same error. Why it is considering the hdfs path even though i am giving input path of local.
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.partitions.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /C:/SparkCourse/Datasets/Amount_spent_by_customer.txt from hdfs://localhost:9000/C:/SparkCourse/Datasets/Amount_spent_by_customer.txt is not a valid DFS filename.
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:197)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
You have to put `file:///` before the input path.

Like this:

```
inputFile=spark.read.option("header",True).option("multiline",True).option("escape",""").csv('file:///F:\spark\sample_files\column_containing_JSON_data.csv')
```